# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.exists()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer reference while using firebase firestore and my app is crashing. Here's my code :

```
private FirebaseFirestore fstore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

private DocumentReference documentReference=fstore.collection("users").document("17030121084");
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    String semester=documentSnapshot.getString("sem");
                    sem.setText(semester);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The sem here refers to my field in my document 17030121084.

Can someone please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was an error while trying to read the document, the `documentSnapshot` variable will be `null`. So your code needs to check for that.

The simplest way to do so is by adding a simple `null` check:

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (document != null && documentSnapshot.exists()){
        String semester=documentSnapshot.getString("sem");
        sem.setText(semester);
    }
}
```

But the above code is not handling the error yet. And since clearly `document` is `null` in your situation, you'll actually need to know what the error is in order to be able to fix it.

So this is a better approach:

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
        String semester=documentSnapshot.getString("sem");
        sem.setText(semester);
    }
}
```

Note that this code closely matches what's in the documentation on [listening for documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), so I highly recommend spending some time there.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the permissions and it worked for me.